# Move player in an arc in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my player (sphere) move in an arc around a semicircle, so whe pressed the left arrow key it should move to the left following the circunference of the circle, here is a picture:

[image]

For this I'm trying to use the Lerp function but without success:

```
Vector3 pos = new Vector3(
    startPos.x + Mathf.Sin(Mathf.PI * 2 * counter / 360),
    startPos.y - Mathf.Sin(Mathf.PI * 2 * counter / 360),
    startPos.z
);

transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, pos, 1f);
```

Comment: You are lerping with factor `1` .. this basically equals `transform.position = pos;` if you want to lerp the factor should be between 0 and 1 ... Anyway Lerp only interpolates between two positions on a direct line ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are linearly interpolating from your start point to your end point. It gives you an intermediate position on the *line* that connects those 2 points.

If you only want to obtain what you described, the easiest and fastest way imho would be to create a parent to your object, centered on the center of your desired arch, then make your object a child of that.

Then you can `parentObject.transform.Rotate()` the parent.

Comment: That was a great suggestion, it works perfectly, thanks!